# How to generate package.xml file for pear

Tags: pear

I just need a tool to generate this file. I've seen there is a tool called pfm (pear file manager), but it's in alpha and I got errors when I try to run `pear build`:

```
s3v3n@s3v3n-laptop:~/dev/project/modules/custommodule$ pear build
running: phpize
Cannot find config.m4.
Make sure that you run '/usr/bin/phpize' in the top level source directory of 
the module `phpize' failed
```

I have doubts about the second pfm question:

```
Enter the base install directory*:
```

I typed `/`. Could this be the problem? What should I enter instead?

If you know other tools that work fine, please suggest them too.

Comment: Solved. Should run `pear package` instead of `pear build`. Sorry guys.

Comment: Add your solution as an answer and accept it. Currently your question shows up as "unanswered"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `pear build` is not the correct command to generate the package.xml file.
The correct command is: `pear package`.